# How to run a mixed language program

Tags: c, assembly

I want to write a mixed language program where part of the code will be written in C, and part of the code in assembly. I was given a sample code, so i know what should my work look like.

```
 .globl _addArrayinA

_addArrayinA:
    pushl %ebp
    movl  %esp,%ebp
    subl  $8,%esp
    movl  8(%ebp), %ebx
    xorl  %esi,%esi
    xor   %eax,%eax

bak:
    addl  (%ebx),%eax
    addl  $4,%ebx
    incl  %esi
    cmpl  $10, %esi
    jne   bak

    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl  %ebp
    ret
 # Return value is in %ea
```

Above is the assembly part.

```
int  addArrayinC(int *myArray, int num)
{
    int c;
    int i;

    c = 0;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        {c += *myArray;
        myArray++;
        }

    return (c);


}
```

This is the second function written in C.
And below is the main file, which is supposed to use two functions above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int addArrayinC(int *numbers,int count);
extern int addArrayinA(int *numbers, int count);

    int main(void) {
        int mynumbers[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
        int sum;


        sum = addArrayinC(mynumbers, 10);
        printf("\nThe sum of array computed in C  is : %d ",sum);


        sum = addArrayinA(mynumbers, 10);
        printf("\nThe sum of array computed in assembly is : %d ",sum);


        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

I tried to open these three files in codeblocks, but could not get to run them. I have no idea how to run a mixed language program. Generally, I use cloud9 for compilations of code. Anyways... How can i run code like this?

Comment: you  could try inline assembly  in c . https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html

Comment: Hey thanks! now everything works...

Comment: Never knew it was possible to inline asm.
Although that's not what exactly i was looking for it works fine i think... 
Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't recommend inline assembly unless you know what you are doing. GCC inline assembly is rather powerful but is also very unforgiving. You can make code that seems to work but if done incorrectly may fail to work later on leading to hard to track bugs. David Wohlferd an SO contributor has an article on the GCC's GNU website about the perils of using Inline assembler: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Comment: inline assembly is definitely an advanced topic I would avoid it, I do avoid it at all costs anyway with decades of experience.  C compiles to assembly which is then assembled into an object, you can just use the toolchains assembler to make an object then link them.  The toolchains often let you either include the assembly on the compile command line or the objects on the compile command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem here. Please note: the extension of the assembler source file has to be `.s` or `.S`(upper case if you want the file to be preprocessed e.g. for #define).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can't even add .s file to my project. I can only add asm file from MASM, but does not work either.

Comment: @IrakliKoberidze: Rename `dad.asm` to `dad.s`. Remove `dad.asm` from project (right click on `dad.asm` in the management window).  Add `dad.s` (right click on `assem`). Add the second .c-file to this project (`assem`). Build and run the project (Key `F9` or by the menu Build/Build and run)..

Comment: Thanks it helped!

Answer (score 0):

fun.c

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
  return(x+1);
}
```

build and examine

```
gcc -c -O2 fun.c -o fun.o
objdump -D fun.o
```

producing

```
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
   3:   c3                      retq
```

So we can make fun.s

```
.globl fun
fun:
  lea 0x1(%rdi),%eax
  retq

as fun.s -o fun.o
objdump -D fun.o

0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
   3:   c3                      retq
```

C code so.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x );

int main ( void )
{
    printf("%u\n",fun(1));
    printf("%u\n",fun(2));
    printf("%u\n",fun(3));
    return(0);
}
```

gcc lets you feed it assembly language

```
gcc so.c fun.s -o so
./so
2
3
4
```

as well as objects

```
gcc so.c fun.o
./so
2
3
4
```

so you dont have to mess with the linker directly